# integration of FlurryAds

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ads, flurry

I am trying to integrate the flurryAds to my iPhone app, I am not able to do this.
I import the .h files named

```
#import "Flurry.h"
#import "FlurryAds.h"
#import "FlurryAdDelegate.h"
```

when I initialize using line of code like

```
[Flurry startSession:@"DV2B6SYZTHSJ5230458"];
[FlurryAds initialize:self.viewController];
```

I get an error like

```
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FlurryHttpAsyncTask", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libFlurryAds.a(libFlurryAds.a-i386-master.o)
```

Can any one help me for this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: you want to integration FlurryAds or flurry Analytics..?

Comment: I want to integrate FlurryAds...

Answer (score 2):

I guess your project is for iPhone/iPad. i386 is for mac project.

So remove i386 from valid architecture.

See this image:  http://postimage.org/image/pxz2fyij5/

Or, one other chance is you are using Mac Flurry Lib...use iphone version of flurry lib.

Comment: then are you using iphone version of Flurry Lib? I guess its mac version..so you get error for i386

Comment: no, I am using flurry lib for iphone. I followed the steps from this [link](http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Publisher/GettingStarted).

Comment: I've been reviewing your suggested edits. Can you tell me where it says that "Thanks" are not allowed on SO?

Comment: @iPhoneProcessor They're allowed; just not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the below required frameworks inside your app?

MediaPlayer.framework

SystemConfiguration.framework

UIKit.framework

CoreGraphics.framework

(Full disclosure: I work in the Support team at Flurry)

Answer (score 0):

Check [this link](http://web-c3.anscamobile.com/forum/2012/12/07/implementing-flurry-ads). See if it helps.

Try removing the -ObjC flag and then see if you still get the error.